# nginx: How to redirect to another domain while using password-authentication?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, password, nginx

I'm trying to redirect domain.com to domain2.com using Nginx. And the user should only be redirected with a correct password.

I achieved the redirecting and the password-authentication. But combing those two doesn't work.

Here is my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name domain.com;

            location /thisOne {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                return 301 http://domain2.com:8080/thisOne/;
            }
        }
```

Can someone please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `return` statement is evaluated before the `auth` statements. You can move the `return` statement into another block to force the evaluation order you are looking for.

For example:

```
location /thisOne {
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    try_files _nonexistent_ @thisOne;
}
location @thisOne {
    return 301 http://domain2.com:8080/thisOne/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem!

Comment: And how do I combine that with proxy_pass? If I write "proxy_pass" instead of "return 301", it says syntax error.

Comment: `proxy_pass` does not suffer from the same early evaluation problem as `return`, so it should work with your original configuration.

Comment: Oh okay. So I tried it with 
`  location /thisOne {
                auth_basic "Restricted Content";
                auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
                proxy_pass http://domain2.com:8080/thisOne/;
            } ` 
but than I get an Redirect-Error saying: the called website redirects the request so that it can never be completed

Comment: I got it. I used the IP for domain2 instead of domain2 and it worked.